# Curl to host and port not working from inside Docker container

Tags: docker, rhel8

Below are the containers:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
7ba94a1bd249        docker-elk_kibana          "/usr/local/bin/dumb…"   27 minutes ago      Up 27 minutes       0.0.0.0:5601->5601/tcp                           docker-elk_kibana_1
267c7f8136a8        docker-elk_elasticsearch   "/tini -- /usr/local…"   27 minutes ago      Up 27 minutes       0.0.0.0:9200->9200/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9300->9300/tcp   elasticsearch
```

Ran curl from inside Container:

```
bash-4.2$ curl -v http://10.206.2.97:9200
* About to connect() to 10.206.2.97 port 9200 (#0)
*   Trying 10.206.2.97...
* No route to host
* Failed connect to 10.206.2.97:9200; No route to host
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed connect to 10.206.2.97:9200; No route to host
```

Ran same curl from host which is connecting fine:

```
[root@pla11010 docker-elk]# curl -v http://10.206.2.97:9200
* Rebuilt URL to: http://10.206.2.97:9200/
*   Trying 10.206.2.97...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 10.206.2.97 (10.206.2.97) port 9200 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 10.206.2.97:9200
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
< content-length: 541
```

Problem, is from inside docker container, not able to curl for connecting to host machine and port 9200.

```
[root@pla11010 docker-elk]# getenforce
Permissive


[root@pla11010 docker-elk]# cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
VERSION="8.0 (Ootpa)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VERSION_ID="8.0"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.0 (Ootpa)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:8.0:GA"
HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"

REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=8.0
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0"
```

Firewall  is disabled. and ping host is working inside Container. Kindly let me know what would be the issue in connecting to host and port from inside Container?

Comment: maybe you have firewalld or iptables service activated on that host

Comment: firewall is disabled.Unit iptables.service could not be found.

Comment: check your routing, ip r s and try to ping the host

Comment: ip r s from inside docker container? on host ip r s  output:[root@pla11010 docker-elk]# ip r s
default via 10.206.0.1 dev ens192 proto static metric 100
10.206.0.0/16 dev ens192 proto kernel scope link src 10.206.2.97 metric 100
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
172.30.0.0/16 dev br-275def012b2e proto kernel scope link src 172.30.0.1
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown
192.168.192.0/20 dev docker_gwbridge proto kernel scope link src 192.168.192.1 linkdown

Comment: are you able to ping the host from outside? the host is able to connect to the network?

Comment: ya, i am able to get response if i ping this host from other machine.

Comment: Please edit your question and include your routing table: `ip r s` . Also you need to update your system.

Comment: updated as not able to curl on host and port from inside the container.`[root@pla11010 docker-elk]# ip r s
default via 10.206.0.1 dev ens192 proto static metric 100
10.206.0.0/16 dev ens192 proto kernel scope link src 10.206.2.97 metric 100
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
172.30.0.0/16 dev br-275def012b2e proto kernel scope link src 172.30.0.1
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown
192.168.192.0/20 dev docker_gwbridge proto kernel scope link src 192.168.192.1 linkdown
`

Comment: Again, you need to edit your question. That's not really readable as a comment.

Comment: Question is edited

Comment: Where is the output from `ip r s`?